# Javascript Onclick, won't work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap as framework.
I'm new in JS so help me out.

I need a "button value" to change when clicked.
Button looks like this:

```
<button id="btn_out" name="btn_in_out" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger primary col-xs-offset-7" type="submit" onclick="sayThanks()" value="out">Ut</button>
```

And here is my JS:

```
<script>
    function sayThanks(){
        var element = document.getElementByld('btn_out');
        element.innerHTML="Tack";
</script>
```

It's place between "head" tags.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Among other problems, you don't have a closing `}` for your function.

Comment: getElementById, not Byld.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `getElementByld` to `getElementById`(with an I) and close the function curly brace

```
function sayThanks(){
        var element = document.getElementById('btn_out');
        element.innerHTML="Tack";
  }
```

```js
function sayThanks(){
        var element = document.getElementById('btn_out');
        element.innerHTML="Tack";
  }
```

```html
<button id="btn_out" name="btn_in_out" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger primary col-xs-offset-7" type="submit" onclick="sayThanks()" value="out">Ut</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled the `getElementById`: `getElementById` not `getElementByld`

http://jsfiddle.net/hn0j9tra/

If you use inline javascript, you should provide an id as a parameters into your function:

```
<script>
    function sayThanks(id){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="Tack";
    }
</script>

<button id="btn_out" name="btn_in_out" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger primary col-xs-offset-7" type="submit"  value="out" onclick="sayThanks(this.id)">Ut</button>
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3jm8qow4/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of problems

1.`getElementById` misspelled

2.Missing closing `}`

```
function sayThanks(){
        var element = document.getElementById('btn_out');
        element.innerHTML="Tack";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you misstyped the function getElementBy**l**d and did not close the whole function itself. If you changed it to getElementById it is probably going to work.

```
<button id="btn_out" name="btn_in_out" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger primary col-xs-offset-7" type="submit" onclick="sayThanks()" value="out">Ut</button>

function sayThanks(){
    var tE = document.getElementById('btn_out');
    if (tE) tE.innerHTML = 'Tack';
}
```

Furthermore, I would just pass the element to the function instead of searching for it, since it is the caller anyway.

```
<button id="btn_out" name="btn_in_out" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger primary col-xs-offset-7" type="submit" onclick="sayThanks(this)" value="out">Ut</button>

function sayThanks(e){
    e.innerHTML = 'Tack';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help you

***html:***

```
 <button id="btn_out" name="btn_in_out" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger primary col-xs-offset-7" type="submit"  value="out">Ut</button>
```

***javascript:***

```
document.getElementById("btn_out").onclick = sayThanks;

    function sayThanks(){
        this.innerHTML="Tack";
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jm8qow4/)